# db2, roll up unknown number of rows from case statement result

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to write a query where I can concatenate some rows into a single column based on the result of the case statement in DB2 v9.5

The contractId can be a variable number of rows as well.

Given I have the following table structure

```
Table1
+------------+------------+------+
| ContractId | Reference  | Code |
+------------+------------+------+
| 12         | P123456789 | A    |
| 12         | A987654321 | B    |
| 12         | 9995559971 | C    |
| 12         | 3215654778 | D    |
| 13         | abcdef     | A    |
| 15         | asdfa      | B    |
| 37         | 282jd      | B    |
| 89         | asdf82     | C    |
+------------+------------+------+
```

I would like to get the output of the result like so

```
+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------+
| ContractId  | Reference with Code A | Other References                   |
+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------+
| 12          | P123456789            | A987654321, 9995559971, 3215654778 |
| 13          | abcdef                | asdfa, 282jd, asdf82               |
+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------+
```

I've tried queries like

```
select t1.contract_id,
max(case when t1.code = A then t1.reference end) as "reference with code a",
max(case when t1.code in ('B','C','D') then t1.reference end) as 'other references
from table t1
group by t1.contractId
```

however, this is still giving me an output like

```
+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+
| ContractId  | Reference with Code A | Other References |
+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+
| 12          | P123456789            | null             |
| 12          | null                  | A987654321       |
| 12          | null                  | 9995559971       |
| 12          | null                  | 3215654778       |
+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+
```

I've also attempted using some of the XML Agg functions but can't seem to get it to format the way I want it too.